# Determining Why Clojure REPL (load-file) and cake build yield error

Tags: clojure

Since Clojure 1.3, I am confused about the directory structure needed to build something in Clojure. I am using cake to build and cake repl.

Here is what works. I have a working build directory addr_verify. The main's and ns's name is addr-verify. The project.clj refers to addr-verify as main, and in addr_verify/src there is addr_verify.clj. The ns inside addr_verify.clj refers to the addr-verify name space.

Now, I had a directory mr1, but cake won't compile it right at line 1

```
(ns mr1
  (use ['clojure.string :only '(split)])
  (use ['clojure.string :only '(join)])
  )
```

If mr1 is a bad name, what naming convention should I use?

I have tried mr1_app as a directory structure using mr1-app as the main name and ns name. I

For mr1 as the directory and ns name, I get

```
Caused by: clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable, compiling:(mr1.clj:1)
```

I'm just not getting what I'm doing wrong here, and I know it's probably something really simple.

### Edit:

Why does the binary mr1 not have a main?

mr1/project.clj

```
(defproject mr1 "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "TODO: add summary of your project"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.cli "0.1.0"]]
   :main mr1)
```

mr1/src/mr1.clj

```
(ns mr1
    (:use [clojure.string :only [split]]
          [clojure.string :only [join]]))

(def grid-dim (atom '(0 0)))
(def mr1-pos (atom '(0 0)))
(def mr2-pos (atom '(0 0)))

(defn cvt-str-to-int
    [string]
   (map #(Integer/parseInt %)
    (split string #" ")))

(defn prompt-for-grid-dim
    []
    (do
        (println "Enter the dimensions of the grid (10 10) ")
        (cvt-str-to-int (read-line))
    ))

(defn prompt-for-rover-pos
    [rover-num]
    (do
        (println "Enter rover's initial position on the grid (2 4) ")
        (cvt-str-to-int (read-line))
    ))

(defn prompt-for-rover-moves
    []
    (do
        (println "Enter rover's moves LMMRM ")
        (read-line)
    ))

(defn -main 
    [& args]
    (do
       (reset! grid-dim (cvt-str-to-int (prompt-for-grid-dim)))
       (reset! mr1-pos (cvt-str-to-int (prompt-for-rover-pos)))
    ) 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with the "syntax" of your namespace declaration. Instead, try this:

```
(ns mr1
    (:use [clojure.string :only [split]]
          [clojure.string :only [join]]))
```

Change your :main setting in project.clj accordingly: it should just be `mr1`, contrary to what I said earlier.

Edited according the comment of googolplex

Comment: Your answer solved the loading into the repl problem. But now when I try to build, I get a bin, but with no main. I'm going to go edit the original question and post all the source code.

Comment: do you have a :main setting in the project.clj ?

Comment: I think your :main should be: mr1.mr1, so: projectname dot namespacename

Comment: I'm appreciative you got it so I can build in the repl.

Comment: I see that the project directory is called mr instead of mr1, I don't know if this could be the cause of the bug.

Comment: Think I found out about your last issue: the namespace name should also be mr1.mr1

Comment: Making namespace to look like `mr1.mr1` is not obligatory. In fact in this case (I mean, in current directory layout, where `mr1.clj` lies directly under `src`) it is wrong. Namespace names have the same rules about hierarchy as java classes do: dot in namespace name is translated to / in directory layout. If you put file with `(ns a.b ...)` to file e.g. `b.clj` directly under `src` and try to compile it, you will get FileNotFoundException. At least this is so with leiningen.

Comment: also, `:main`  shouldn't be in form `projectname.namespacename`. It should be simply a namespace.

Comment: Guess I was confused about the project name being the same as the namespace name. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

Since the first part has already been answered, I will answer the part about `:main`.
As [sample.project.clj](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj#L95) file says, `:main` key should have as an assigned value a namespace which contains `-main` function. So you should have such function

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (do-things-you-want-to-do-on-program-start))
```

in your mr1.clj. Also AFAIR if you want to use your program as a standalone jar you have to have this namespace gen-classed. By this I mean that you have to:

1. Include `:gen-class` option in your namespace definition like this:

   ```
   (ns mr1
     (:gen-class)
     ...other options...)
   ```
2. Make the namespace AOT-compiled (AOT stands for Ahead Of Time). To do this you need to specify your namespace in the list of AOT-compiled namespaces in project.clj:

   ```
   (defproject mr1 "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
     ...other definitions...
     :aot [mr1]
     :main mr1)
   ```

After you've done this, you can use `cake` to generate executable jar for you.

ADD:
I think it is worth to note that you don't have to have a `:main` at all. If all you want to do is to run your program in repl or if you want to create a library, there can be no gen-classes namespaces (except if you want to interact with plain java code in such a way that java code can call your clojure code) and no `:main` namespace, which are required only for executable jars.

Comment: He has a -main function, but you have to scroll for it to see (at least I had to).

Comment: I don't know if "lein bin" works the exact same way as cake, but in 1.3 you shouldn't have to do :gen-class or :aot https://github.com/Raynes/lein-bin if it is the case. Not sure though!

Comment: Yeah, I missed `-main` function :)

Comment: 1.3 means clojure-1.3.0? In this case I'm afraid you're wrong. Consider this: https://gist.github.com/1462765 (test.clj should be in src in real project). If you remove either `:gen-class` from test.clj or `:aot` from project.clj and do `lein uberjar`, you will get a jar which cannot be launched. lein-bin depends on uberjar, so it does require `:gen-class` and `:aot` too. I don't think that cake is that different so it won't require it, since this is general way the clojure works. If you want to get a class from namespace, you simply must to AOT-compile the namespace.

Comment: Hmm, maybe cake-generated binaries work in such way that they launch the namespace directly as a script? In such case `:gen-class` really shouldn't be required, but this is not very clean way to make the program work, since main classes functionality of jars is the method to make executable programs, and it is kinda against java platform practices to do otherwise, I think.