# Structuring Clojure cake build environment

Tags: clojure

I have a clojure application called mr1; its project.clj is located in ./mr1/, and mr1.clj is located in ./mr1/src.

I cannot figure out how to structure the directories, namespace, and project.clj file correctly, so I can build a binary using cake bin.

Enclosed are my current project.clj and the head and tail of mr1.clj.

src/mr1.clj loads fine into cake repl and executes. cake bin produces an mr1 file that contains no -main.

```
(defproject mr1 "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "TODO: add summary of your project"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.cli "0.1.0"]]
   :main mr1)

(ns mr1
    (:use [clojure.string :only [split]]
          [clojure.string :only [join]]))
```

.
.
.

```
(defn -main 
    [& args]
    (do
       (reset! grid-dim (prompt-for-grid-dim))
       (reset! mr1-pos (prompt-for-rover-pos 1))
       (let [moves (prompt-for-rover-moves)]
           (execute-each-move moves @mr1-pos))

       (reset! mr2-pos (prompt-for-rover-pos 2))
       (let [moves (prompt-for-rover-moves)]
           (execute-each-move moves @mr2-pos))


    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in answer to your [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465157/determining-why-clojure-repl-load-file-and-cake-build-yield-error), you have to enable AOT-compilation of your namespace. I've copied that answer here in case if someone would have same problem.

As [sample.project.clj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465157/determining-why-clojure-repl-load-file-and-cake-build-yield-error) file says, `:main` key should have as an assigned value a namespace which contains `-main` function. So you should have such function

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (do-things-you-want-to-do-on-program-start))
```

in your mr1.clj. Also AFAIR if you want to use your program as a standalone jar you have to have this namespace gen-classed. By this I mean that you have to:

1. Include `:gen-class` option in your namespace definition like this:

   ```
   (ns mr1
     (:gen-class)
     ...other options...)
   ```
2. Make the namespace AOT-compiled (AOT stands for Ahead Of Time). To do this you need to specify your namespace in the list of AOT-compiled namespaces in project.clj:

   ```
   (defproject mr1 "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
     ...other definitions...
     :aot [mr1]
     :main mr1)
   ```

After you've done this, you can use `cake` to generate executable jar for you.

Comment: I'm sorry for the collision, and thanks for answering this, as well.